# Javascript. как вернуть значение функции onreadystatechange?

Tags: javascript

Как переменной "value" присвоить полученное значение, которое пришло в качестве ответа от веб-сервера?

```
    var value;
    ...
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            //alert(xhr.responseText);
            var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            value = jsonResponse.id;
            //return value;
        }
        else {
          console.error(xhr.statusText);
        }
//return value;
    };
    ...
```

Comment: Присваивается оно легко, но неизвестно когда.

Comment: если я правильно понял, то вы пытаетесь использовать value прежде чем произойдет xhr.onreadystatechange, скорее всего вам необходимо в теле xhr.onreadystatechange вызвать функцию которая будет содержать реализацию логики и передать в нее value . Либо уточните вопрос.

Comment: @papiroca, первоначально я value не использую, а хочу полученное значение передать следующим шагом в функцию:
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({data: value});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы и так присваиваете параметр из ответа переменной *value* . Но судя по всему у вас вопрос совсем в другом.
Вы делаете асинхронный запрос, полностью это у вас выглядит скорее всего примерно так:

> ```
> var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
> xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
>     if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
>         //alert(xhr.responseText);
>         var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
>         value = jsonResponse.id;
>     }
>     else {
>       console.error(xhr.statusText);
>     }
> };
> xhr.open("GET",url, true);
> xhr.send();
> ```

запрос отправляется в момент *xhr.send()*, а функция *xhr.onreadystatechange* отработает, когда придет ответ. Когда это произойдет по большому счету не известно.
Что бы использовать данные из ответа, вам нужно в callback функции вызвать действие которое должно использовать переменную *value*, например так:

```
var value;
function useValue() {
   // Делаете то что вам нужно
}
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        //alert(xhr.responseText);
        var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        value = jsonResponse.id;
        useValue();
    }
    else {
      console.error(xhr.statusText);
    }
};
```

Comment: До меня уже дошло. Всем спасибо за помощь!

Comment: и лучше быть аккуратнее с зоной видимости и передавать useValue(value) без var value;

Comment: да, естественно, но переменная value может использоваться у автора и в других местах.

Comment: Как думаете, сколько еще раз вы сможете ответить на этот вопрос, прежде чем сорветесь? :)